# Calculo de diferencias horarias en Java

Tags: java

tengo una BDD que tiene un campo en Timestamp,el registro lo crea en la BDD según la zona horaria del servidor la cual puedo conocer.

Por otro lado la GUI está en otra zona horaria (También la puedo conocer) . Alguién me puede ayudar a convertir la hora que viene de la BDD (con su zona horaria) a la que se visualizará en la GUI (en su zona horaria) o que API puedo usar de forma mas eficiente.

Gracias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077142/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-zoneddatetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sacado de aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571931/java-sql-timestamp-changing-timezone-of-timestamp

Traducido básicamente lo que dice es que java.sql.TimeStamp no tiene time zones, son instantes en el tiempo como java.util.Date.

Lo que si puedes hacer es cambiar usando la clase LocalDateTime, (que existe a partir de JAVA 1.8), para que te aplique el offset de tu zona horaria.

```
 Timestamp tiempoUTC= new Timestamp(
                ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 8, 25, 11, 23, 46, 0,
                        ZoneId.of("UTC")
                ).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        LocalDateTime momento=tiempoUTC.toLocalDateTime();

        System.out.println("Momento: "+momento);
```

El resultado de este código es:

```
Momento: 2018-08-25T13:23:46
```

Como ves, al tener yo un Locale con offset de +2, me cambia la hora que yo tenia, sumandole 2 horas